# Why Tkinter does not display basic counter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning the basics about Python and Tkinter, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php).

The thing is, the last exercise of that tutorial is

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0

def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        global counter
        counter += 1
        label.config(text=str(counter))
        label.after(1000,count)
    count()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title ("Counting")
label = tk.Label(root, fg = "green")
label.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem I have is that no number is shown in the app, although the application and the stop button work fine. I have been looking for an answer, but I haven't found any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never call `counter_label`. Read over the tutorial code again.

Comment: Yes, I read the tutorial. In the code the function is not called, but in the image the counter is running, so I want to make it run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `counter_label(label)` right before `root.mainloop()`. It should work as expected.

Keep in mind in order for a function to work you will need to call that function at some point in your code. Just having the function without calling it will result in lots of nothing.

Also this line:

```
label.config(text=str(counter))
```

The `str()` section is not needed. You can delete that and just leave `counter`

Like this:

```
label.config(text=counter)
```

Tkinter labels can take a string or an int. Its not an issue.

In addition if you move `label.config(text=str(counter))` above `counter += 1` in your count function your counter will start at zero instead of 1.

Comment: I was blind! Of course, you got the call the function. Thank you very much.

Also, I was wondering why that "str" was there. So... there's no need, right? That's awesome.

PS: I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Vento You can select a single answer using the check mark under the down arrow if you feel like the answer was the most helpful one to you.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Why does Tkinter not display basic counter?"*

It *does* display the counter(if that's referring to the `label` that the counter supposed to increase), it's just that the `label` displays an empty string since nothing has updated it. Add:

```
label['text'] = 0
```

to see that the label actually exists.

As [Carcigenicate points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153332/why-tkinter-does-not-display-basic-counter#comment85311082_49153332), you never call the function to actually modify the label. Assuming you'd want a chronometer of a second, add the lines above and below before `root.mainloop()`:

```
root.after(1000, counter_label, label)
```

Comment: Why all the complicated information? all the OP needs is `counter_label(label)` before the mainloop. There is no need to `label['text'] = 0` as the counter variable already exist and is being used for the text field of `label`. Though they could remove the `str()` potion.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Sure but the counter otherwise starts from value 1. I believe my addition makes the counter more consistent.

Comment: Not if they move the `label.config(text=str(counter))` above `counter += 1`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I agree that it would be a better solution.

Comment: I know your solution is valid. I just think its a bit more advanced than a beginner would know or fully understand.

Comment: Thank you, I've read the conversation and the comments have been very useful.